# How to detect Android phone using php?

Tags: javascript, php, android

If a user surfs to my site I want to display a message if he using Android phone. My website is `http://website.com`

How can I do this?

I have tried this but not succeeded:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

Comment: The whole internet? I did a google search on "detect android phone php" and it got more than enough results.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can detect Android user agent using PHP and Javascript also :

## With  PHP:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    echo "your message";
}
```

---

## With JavaScript:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    alert('Your message');
}
```

Comment: strtolower lowercases the string, so no need to do stripos, just strpos

Answer (score 2):

For PHP:

`$isAndroid = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAndroid() {
    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') !== false) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(isAndroid()) {
    echo "an android device";
} else {
    echo "non-android device";
}
```